# Drupal menu link not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I pulled a live drupal 7 site into MAMP and uninstalled domain access modules that had been installed. After doing that, I am now getting this error

```
The requested URL "/flockstate/admin/structure/menu/item/1857/edit" was not found on this server.
```

This error only shows up when i want to edit or delete a menu item.

I have checked the settings.php and .htaccess files and they seem ok

How do i fix this?

Comment: use drush cc all , clear all caches , and rebuild registry ! if you have trouble again , try to execute update.php

Comment: I have done all this and no change. recently i installed apachesolr on the same local site and the index page of apachesolr now shows the sam eerror

Comment: Finally found the problem in my settings.php file. I had fast_404 enabled with settings in settings.php. I uninstalled the modules and removed the settings and viola! It worked